# I am unable to open firefox browser through selenium3

Tags: selenium-firefoxdriver

As the title states, I cannot open FireFox through selenium3. I tried all possible combinations

selenium 3
firefox latest version 54.0.1 (verified 32 bit or 64 bit)

Below is my code:

```
/*   public class testing {

    public static WebDriver  d;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\geckodriver.exe");
        d = new FirefoxDriver();

        d.manage().window().maximize();

        d.get("https://www.google.com");

    }

}
*/
```

I am getting the following error:

```
/* org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
    lse,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"54.0.1","maxVersion":"54.0.1"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"seen":true,"dependencies":[],"hasEmbeddedWebExtension":false,"userPermissions":null}
    1502430891044   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
    1502430891046   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
    1502430891046   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
    1502430891046   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
    1502430891047   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
    1502430891050   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi
    1502430891051   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on aushelper@mozilla.org version 2.0
    1502430891052   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
    1502430891053   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.50
    1502430891053   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
    1502430891054   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.5
    1502430891055   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\screenshots@mozilla.org.xpi
    1502430891055   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on screenshots@mozilla.org version 6.6.0
    1502430891055   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
    1502430891056   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on webcompat@mozilla.org version 1.1
    1502430891060   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
    1502430891060   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
    1502430891060   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
    1502430891060   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
    1502430891060   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
    1502430891061   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
    1502430891065   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
    1502430891065   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
    1502430891066   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
    1502430891066   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
    1502430891066   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
    1502430891066   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
    1502430892611   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
    1502430892612   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
    1502430892613   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
    1502430892768   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
    1502430892768   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 19
    1502430892768   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
    1502430892785   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
    1502430892786   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
    1502430892834   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
    1502430892940   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
    1502430892940   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
    1502430892940   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
    1502430892944   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
    1502430892945   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
    1502430892968   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
    1502430892973   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
    [GPU 120] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346

        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:112)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
        at ggg.w.main(w.java:13)
    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: 
    lse,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"54.0.1","maxVersion":"54.0.1"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"seen":true,"dependencies":[],"hasEmbeddedWebExtension":false,"userPermissions":null}
    1502430891044   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
    1502430891046   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
    1502430891046   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
    1502430891046   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
    1502430891047   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
    1502430891050   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi
    1502430891051   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on aushelper@mozilla.org version 2.0
    1502430891052   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
    1502430891053   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.50
    1502430891053   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
    1502430891054   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.5
    1502430891055   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\screenshots@mozilla.org.xpi
    1502430891055   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on screenshots@mozilla.org version 6.6.0
    1502430891055   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
    1502430891056   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on webcompat@mozilla.org version 1.1
    1502430891060   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
    1502430891060   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
    1502430891060   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
    1502430891060   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
    1502430891060   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
    1502430891061   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
    1502430891065   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
    1502430891065   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
    1502430891066   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
    1502430891066   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
    1502430891066   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
    1502430891066   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
    1502430892611   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
    1502430892612   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
    1502430892613   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
    1502430892768   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
    1502430892768   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 19
    1502430892768   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
    1502430892785   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
    1502430892786   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
    1502430892834   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
    1502430892940   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
    1502430892940   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
    1502430892940   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
    1502430892944   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
    1502430892945   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
    1502430892968   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
    1502430892973   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
    [GPU 120] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346

    Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
    System info: host: 'CI018', ip: '192.168.60.15', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
    Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:124)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
        at ggg.w.main(w.java:13)
    Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
    lse,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"54.0.1","maxVersion":"54.0.1"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"seen":true,"dependencies":[],"hasEmbeddedWebExtension":false,"userPermissions":null}
    1502430891044   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
    1502430891046   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
    1502430891046   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
    1502430891046   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
    1502430891047   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
    1502430891050   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi
    1502430891051   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on aushelper@mozilla.org version 2.0
    1502430891052   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
    1502430891053   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.50
    1502430891053   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
    1502430891054   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.5
    1502430891055   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\screenshots@mozilla.org.xpi
    1502430891055   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on screenshots@mozilla.org version 6.6.0
    1502430891055   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
    1502430891056   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on webcompat@mozilla.org version 1.1
    1502430891060   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
    1502430891060   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
    1502430891060   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
    1502430891060   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
    1502430891060   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
    1502430891061   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
    1502430891065   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
    1502430891065   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
    1502430891066   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
    1502430891066   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
    1502430891066   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
    1502430891066   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
    1502430892611   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
    1502430892612   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
    1502430892613   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
    1502430892768   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
    1502430892768   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 19
    1502430892768   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
    1502430892785   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
    1502430892786   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
    1502430892834   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
    1502430892940   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
    1502430892940   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
    1502430892940   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
    1502430892944   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
    1502430892945   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
    1502430892968   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
    1502430892973   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
    [GPU 120] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346

        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:112)
        ... 7 more
    */
```

I seen so many blogs all are explained get back to lower version, but I don't think that is the correct solution, because everyday Mozilla is updated with better UX. Therefore, I would prefer using the newer version.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is surely the .jar files

Please try and update your jar files to the newest 3.5.0 version and I think your issue will be resolved

Here is the link to get the latest version

http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Hope it helps.

Comment: 1503293852887 geckodriver INFO geckodriver 0.18.0
1503293852896 geckodriver INFO Listening on 127.0.0.1:11493
1503293853566 geckodriver::marionette INFO Starting browser C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]
1503293857812 Marionette INFO Listening on port 53732
1503293859450 Marionette INFO startBrowser ea4a0b7a-9dc8-4f48-851b-4297b648cb45
Aug 21, 2017 11:07:39 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to find width field

Comment: Sorry ....Its working...Thanks for helping....Above error came when i was trying FF older version...Now its updated 53...yes its working fine now...Pls ignore above comment...Hope you undersatnd

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times when its showing error as  "1502430891044   addons.xpi  DEBUG" this was due to version compatibility. Go to this site

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG.

Comment: I think the OP shady resolved the problem as indicated in the comments to the answer from a few weeks ago.